# Ubuntu 3.10 Appearance menu missing

Tags: 13.10, settings, appearance

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 3.10, but I have decided to move back to Unity for a variety of reasons...

I have installed Ubuntu-Desktop all ok.. however one issue is that in the **SETTINGS** Page, there is no **APPEARANCE** Menu.

Can this be manually installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `gnome-control-center-unity` and you will get **APPEARANCE**  Menu in **System Settings**

To install `gnome-control-center-unity` open terminal and type :

`sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-unity`